# vTune, how do I pass input parameters

Tags: intel-vtune

I have developed a simple piece of C code, and launch it by

```
cat input.txt | ./code
```

(so code read input.txt as a stdin)
Question is: how do I simulate that within vTune?

In the vTune Launch Application page, if I fill in the Application parameters field with input.txt, vTune runs for ever for 'Collecting basic hotspot data'.

thanks, mario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a shell script running this command. Specify the path to script in the "Application" field.